# In guile scheme, how to share syntax between outer macro and inner macro?

Tags: macros, scheme, guile

In Guile scheme, I have a macro which calls another macro, and I want the call to the inner macro to reference a symbol used in the inner macro.
Here is a simple example to illustrate the kind of thing I'm trying to acheive:

```
(define-syntax macro1 
  (lambda (x)
    (syntax-case x ()
      ((macro1 expr1)
       (with-syntax ((f (datum->syntax x 'f)))
         #'(lambda (f) expr1))))))

(define-syntax macro2 (lambda (x)
  (syntax-case x ()
    ((macro2 expr2)
     #'(macro1 (expr2 f))))))

((macro2 1+) 2)
```

I expected the final line to return 3, but instead I got the following error:

```
;;; <stdin>:142:0: warning: possibly unbound variable `f'
ice-9/boot-9.scm:1669:16: In procedure raise-exception:
Unbound variable: f
```

Is it possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 3):

OK, so I discoverd how to do this. I have to use #'macro1 instead of x in the `datum->syntax` call:

```
(define-syntax macro1 
  (lambda (x)
    (syntax-case x ()
      ((macro1 expr1)
       (with-syntax ((f (datum->syntax #'macro1 'f)))
         #'(lambda (f) expr1))))))

(define-syntax macro2 (lambda (x)
  (syntax-case x ()
    ((macro2 expr2)
     #'(macro1 (expr2 f))))))
```

Not sure why it doesn't work with x, and I couldn't find any explanation in the manual.

Comment: It doesn't work with `x` because the first argument to `datum->syntax` needs to be an identifier. The value of `#'macro1` is an identifier whereas the value of `x` is a parenthesized expression.